# Can't manage to update a subscribed RHEL Server 6.0

Tags: redhat, licensing, rhel6, subscription

So I'm running a Virtual RHEL Server 6.0 as a lab server (Hosted on Hyper-V) to remember and practice. I managed to RPM install `subscription-manager` package since RHN Classic is no longer up.

To get this done in a clean RHEL 6.0 installation I did the following:

1. Downloaded, installed/upgraded the required dependencies to install the `subscription-manager package`.
2. Then downloaded and installed the lastest SM package available in RH Customer Portal for RHEL 6 (`subscription-manager-1.20.10-8.el6.x86_64.rpm`).
3. After that, I was able to successfully register the system. But when I tried to subscribe, it failed with this error:

> No Installed products on system. No need to attach subscriptions.

4. Due to this error I generated a `.pem` certificate using RH Portal as explained in this link [https://access.redhat.com/solutions/691873](https://access.redhat.com/labs/rhpc/) and then put it in `/etc/pki/product` and ran the commands:

```
# restorecon -Rv /etc/pki/product
# chown root.root /etc/pki/product/69.pem
# chmod 644 /etc/pki/product/69.pem
# rct cat-cert /etc/pki/product/69.pem
```

5. Finally I was able to successfully attach a subscription:

```
[root@rhel6-lab ~]# subscription-manager list
+-------------------------------------------+
    Installed Product Status
+-------------------------------------------+
Product Name:   Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
Product ID:     69
Version:        6.0
Arch:           x86_64
Status:         Subscribed
Status Details:
Starts:         01/30/2022
Ends:           01/30/2025
```

The issue I have is when I run `yum repolist` or try any package installation/upgrade I get an error like this:

```
[root@rhel6-lab ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Setting up Update Process
https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/6/6Server/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] problem with the local client certificate
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: rhel-6-server-rpms. Please verify its path and try again
[root@rhel6-lab ~]#
```

I have tried the following without success:

1. Unsubscribing and subscribing again.
2. Checked whether if the sslclientkey and sslclientcert `.pem` files were in the folder `/etc/pki/entitlement/` according to `/etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo` file.
3. Tried to run `subscription-manager identity --regenerate --force` and run my credentials again.
4. Checked if the path `/var/cache/yum/x86_64/6Server/rhel-6-server-rpms/packages/` existed.
5. Disabled RHN Classic (`/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/rhnplugin.conf`).
6. Reinstalling RHEL 6.0 and subscription-manager.
7. Checking server facts by running `subscription-manager facts --list`.

I also tried subscribing RHEL 6.5 and RHEL 6.10 servers and run updates (to discard RHEL 6 repos being disconnected), both versions allowed me to run updates. I also compared the repo file `/etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo` with version 6.0 and are exactly the same, except for the sslclientkey and sslclientcert of course.

This is my `/etc/yum.conf` file:

```
[root@rhel6-lab ~]# cat /etc/yum.conf
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=3

#  This is the default, if you make this bigger yum won't see if the metadata
# is newer on the remote and so you'll "gain" the bandwidth of not having to
# download the new metadata and "pay" for it by yum not having correct
# information.
#  It is esp. important, to have correct metadata, for distributions like
# Fedora which don't keep old packages around. If you don't like this checking
# interupting your command line usage, it's much better to have something
# manually check the metadata once an hour (yum-updatesd will do this).
# metadata_expire=90m

# PUT YOUR REPOS HERE OR IN separate files named file.repo
# in /etc/yum.repos.d
[root@rhel6-lab ~]#
```

I'm running out of options, can't find the solution to update RHEL 6.0 in spite of being properly subscribed to Customer Portal, I can see the consumed subscription.

Comment: EOL of RH6 end December 1, 2020

Comment: Do you have ELC contract? https://access.redhat.com/articles/4665701

Comment: No, I don't have ELC but I can still update RHEL 6.5 and 6.10. I should be able to get 6.0 updated, right? I'm going to test 6.1 later today to see if the issues is just 6.0 specific. EOL just means it won't receive new updates, but you  should still be able to get the lastest packages available for release until the 6Server repo gets taken down

Comment: So I just installed RHEL 6.1 which already has `subscription-manager` but an older version, which didn't let me subscribe. So I updated to the latest `subscription-manager-1.20.10-8.el6.x86_64.rpm` and I managed to run updates succesfully which may be an issue of RHEL 6.0 specifically, maybe on the server side it does not support the `distribution.version: 6.0` fact.

Comment: `EOL just means it won't receive new updates` it also means it's a security risk and off topic.